# Error in model.frame.default with clusters function

Tags: r

I made a model with Flexmix function. I used a train dataset and I want to predict the results for a new dataset.

I have the following codes:

```
m1 <- stepFlexmix(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4,data=scores_train,control=list(classify="hard"),
                  k=1:10,nrep=20)
model1<-getModel(m1,"AIC")
ypredict<-predict(model1,scores_test)
clust<-clusters(object=model1,newdata=scores_test)
```

Then the following error message appears with the last line of code :

> Error in model.frame.default(model@terms, data = data, na.action = NULL,  : 
>     les longueurs des variables diffèrent (trouvé pour 'X1')`

But when I checked the size of my dataset, everything is right :

```
> length(scores_test$X1)
[1] 381
> length(scores_test$X2)
[1] 381
> length(scores_test$X3)
[1] 381
> length(scores_test$X4)
[1] 381
> is.data.frame(scores_test)
[1] TRUE
```

So I really don't know what does this error mean, is anyone can help?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this error message appears because clusters can't predict clusters for a new dataset in the case of a flexmix model.